# A example of infinite homotopy class of curve from p to q

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

For a differentiable manifold $M$ and $ p,q \in M$ ,let
$$
C_{pq}=\{\text{all curves from p to q}\}   \\
H_{pq}=C_{pq}/\sim   
$$
$\sim$ is homotopy equivalence. Whether there is a differentiable manifold $M$ (finite dimensional) st there are two points $p,q\in M$ st $H_{pq}$ is a infinite set ?

Comment: Are you familiar with fundamental groups?

Comment: @EricWofsey I know the basic concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, and let $p=q=1$. Then $M$ is a 2-dimensional manifold but for each integer $n$, I can find a loop $\gamma_n$ based at $1$ that winds $n$ times counter-clockwise around $0$. Then if $n \ne m$, there is no hope of finding a homotopy from $\gamma_n$ to $\gamma_m$.

This can be proved with basic complex analysis, even if you know no algebraic topology. Thanks Mariano for singling out a "smallest" example.

Comment: I would have gone for $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$!

Comment: Can you prove it with just (easy) complex analysis though? I think you essentially need to prove the fundamental group of the circle is infinite, which is maybe nontrivial to the OP. If memory serves, I knew how to compute complex integrals before I knew $\pi_1(S^1)$...

Comment: Integrate 1/z along curves turning around the whole $n$ times.

Comment: Ok, let's do that.

Comment: Really good example .

Comment: The first example I thought of was $\Bbb{C}\setminus \Bbb{Z}$: a 2-manifold whose fundamental group isn't even finitely generated, let alone finite! Maybe it's worth mentioning that a compact finite dimensional manifold does have finitely generated fundamental group.